# How to arrange two HTML columns, one of which has a fixed part, so they can stack?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, media-queries

I'm sorry but I really cannot find a good title for this question.

Here is the situation. I have the following layout:

[image: Layout]

Each rectangle is a `<div>`. In the red rectangle, I have three buttons that select the contents of the blue and green rectangles.

My current HTML layout is organized like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    contents of red rectangle here
    <div id="info-1">contents of green rectangle</div>
    <div id="info-2">contents of green rectangle</div>
    <div id="info-3">contents of green rectangle</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div id="steps-1">contents of blue rectangle</div>
    <div id="steps-2">contents of blue rectangle</div>
    <div id="steps-3">contents of blue rectangle</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only one of `#info-*` is displayed at a time. Same thing for `#steps-*`. The `div.left` is left floating and `div.right` is right floating.

So this is working fine. **But** now I want to stack them nicely with a media query when the page is viewed with a mobile device. What I would like is the following stack:

- contents of red rectangle
- `info-1`
- `steps-1`
- `info-2`
- `steps-2`
- `info-3`
- `steps-3`

Any way to achieve this stack without JavaScript and still be able to create the above desktop layout?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it is only me, but even though you presented the picture,  the question is quite confusing

Comment: Flexbox is the only way to really reorder elements, and all the elements must be siblings of each other.

Comment: It seems like what you are looking to do is to reorder the dom. In certain cases you can use negative margins or flexbox (you could use flexbox and have a less rad fallback that would still "work") - but you particular layout wouldn't work. Depending on how simple your information is, (like if it was a simple brochure site) you could hide stuff and show stuff  (like whole dom blocks) with the @media rules... or use jQuery to rearrange the dom. You could also build the dom with something on the fly based on screen size, but there would be no going back...  on second thought... I have an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a fiddle [HERE:](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/7sm7c/)

I just made what you wanted for mobile first, and then fooled around with the floats. I'm still not really sure what you want, but I got the divs to stack with absolute positioning and re-ordered them with z-index. From there, I assume you will use a bit of script to reveal the necessary info etc. There are definitely a few *magic* numbers, mainly the height of the "fixed" red navigation. If if were to be truly responsive, you would need to set a listener to find current hight of that div and add that to the top or margin top declaration of the green column - bla bla bla - Hope it helps!

HTML

```
    <div class="top">
        <ul>
            <li>See green01</li>
            <li>See green02</li>
            <li>See green03</li>
            <li>See blue01</li>
            <li>See blue02</li>
            <li>See blue03</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="block green z-01">green01</div>
    <div class="block blue z-01">blue01</div>
    <div class="block green z-02">green01</div>
    <div class="block blue z-02">blue02</div>
    <div class="block green z-03">green03</div>
    <div class="block blue z-03">blue03</div>

</div> <!-- .wrapper -->
```

CSS

```
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
/*     height: 100%; */
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.top {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    height: 30%;
}

.block {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 7em;
}

.green {
    background-color: lime;
}

.blue {
    background-color: lightblue;
}


@media (min-width: 30em) {

    .top {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        background-color: red;
        height: 15em;
    }

    .block {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .green {
        float: left;
        clear: left;

    }

    .blue {
        position: relative;
        top: -15em;
        float: right;
        clear: right;
    }

    .blue {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0
    }

    .green {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15em;
        left: 0
    }

    .z-01 {
        z-index: 3;
    }

    .z-02 {
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .z-03 {
        z-index: 1;    
    }

} /* =================== */
```